# How to restore wordpess backedup files from updraftplus

Tags: wordpress

I have a zipped file got from my client  which is back up file includes all information from about wordpress website like database backup, and template etc.
this file backed with updraftplus from a live host server now I want to restore it on my local machine, i don't know how to restore all zip file but when I am restroing database updraftplus giving me warring like, you are not restring you are migrating.please suggest me how can i restore it on my local machine and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the four different ways which you can choose from (instructions for the first two are then provided):

- Install the UpdraftPlus Migrator component on your source website, and send the backup over directly. (Press the “Clone/Migrate” button on the source website, and follow the instructions shown there).
- OR, download the backup set from your source site (or from your Dropbox, or wherever you stored it), and upload into the ‘Existing Backups’ tab on your destination site.
  OR, set up the destination site to use the same remote storage (e.g. same Dropbox) as the source site, save your settings, and then press the “Rescan remote storage” link in the ‘Existing Backups’ tab on your destination site.
- OR, download the backup set from your source site (or from your Dropbox, or wherever you stored it), and use FTP to upload into the UpdraftPlus folder on your destination site (wp-content/updraft), and press the “Rescan local folder for new backup sets” link in the ‘Existing Backups’ tab on your destination site.

**For more detail, you can check following link :**

https://updraftplus.com/faqs/how-do-i-migrate-to-a-new-site-location/

Comment: Do I have to buy the premium version of updraft?

Comment: No I don't think

Comment: when I am restoring the files updraft giving me this warnning.

Comment: This backup set is from a different site (http://ssti2014.uk.tempcloudsite.com / http://localhost:81/othertest) - this is not a restoration, but a migration. You need the Migrator add-on in order to make this work.